# What is the preferred way of detecting temperature scale on Android?

Tags: android, locale

So options are: use language based detection or use location based detection.

- The language based detection should be mostly fine, unless you're non
  native English speaker like me, use en_US but are used to Celsius
  scale and live outside US.
- The location based detection should be
  mostly fine too, unless you're an European traveling to US or the
  other way around in which case your scale changes as you travel.

Is there some system wide setting for this? Seems like all the weather widgets offer you option to switch between F/C but the best would be to detect the setting value in advance.

Comment: Go for location and don't change while travelling. If you're Polish and you go to US you don't stop using Celsius just because you're in different country right?

Comment: @alex How will the application differentiate between home and foreign country?

Answer (score 3):

> What is the preferred way of detecting temperature scale on Android?

You "detect" it by asking the user what she wants.

If you wish to use one of the other schemes as the default answer, to minimize the need for the user to change the setting, that is fine. However, there is no substitute for giving the user control.

> So options are: use language based detection or use location based detection

Of those two, language-based detection has the major benefit of not requiring a permission.

A third option would be to attempt to use something based off of the mobile country code of the SIM card. That too is no guarantee of being what the user wants, which is why apps need to let the user change your default.

Personally, I would go with language, as it is unlikely to be dramatically worse of a default than the others, and it would be easiest to set up. Have a `res/values/bools.xml` file with an `use_celsius_default` value set to `true`. Have a `res/values-en-rUS/bools.xml` that sets `use_celsius_default` to `false`. Ditto for `rest/values-es-rUS/bools.xml`. In code, `getResources().getBoolean(R.id.use_celsius_default)` will return whether or not to use Celsius as the default temperature unit.

Of course, the physics major in me wants to use Kelvin... :-)

> Is there some system wide setting for this?

Not as of Android 4.4. Similarly, there is no system-wide setting for whether distances are measured in miles or kilometers; whether air pressure is measured in millibars, PSI, or kPa; whether weights are measured in pounds, kilograms, or stone; whether men's shoe sizes run from 3 to 14, from 35 to 48, from 21 to 31, or some other scheme; etc.

Comment: I can't agree with the idea of "You "detect" it by asking the user what she wants.". The OS should try to reduce work when possible, instead of asking it for each app you install. That's why we also have OS level date-format and time-format. It should also have meter-vs-feet choice, currency, etc... It's too bad we don't have this on Android, like on other modern OSs. I think a better thing is to guess what's right (based on estimated location and if that's not possible use the current OS preferences), and then if it's not right, the user can change it.

Answer (score 1):

`getTemperature()` APIs were recently added.

Source: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/features#regional-preferences

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/text/util/LocalePreferences#getTemperatureUnit()